# How to pandadize a for loop that is dependant on the multiplication of a value from a previous row?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I optimize the following code so that it is quite performant for DataFrames with a lot of rows? If possible, a pandas only solution is preferred.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

CONSTANT = 1
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [7, 2, 3], "c": [100, np.nan, np.NaN]})
df["d"] = np.nan

for runner in range(df.shape[0]):
    if runner > 0:
        df.loc[runner, "c"] = df.loc[runner - 1, "d"]
    df.loc[runner, "d"] = df.a.iloc[runner] * int(df.c.iloc[runner] * CONSTANT) + df.c.iloc[runner]

print("df:\n", df)
```

This results in:

```
df:
    a       c       d
0  7   100.0   800.0
1  2   800.0  2400.0
2  3  2400.0  9600.0
```

**EDIT**

On of the contributors mentioned, whether my question from yesterday ([How to add result of previous row to contents of present row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53713297/how-to-add-result-of-previous-row-to-contents-of-present-row)) is identical to this one: indeed, they cover different topics: in this question the results have to be multiplied, in the other question a summation is necessary.

Comment: Try using the "shift" function in Pandas.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind the result? That would be easier than trying to reverse-engineer your code. :)

Comment: @timgeb : yes, for sure: the logic is to take the value of column `a`, multiply it with (a multiple value of) column `c` and add the result of this to column `c`. Put this result in a new column `d`. For subsequent rows, put the value of the previous row of column `d` in column `c` and redo what has been done in the row before.

Comment: @user7468395, you might accept and upvote if an answer fits

Comment: @Zanshin unfortunately both answers are not using pure pandas.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are asking for pandas solution, but the below could be a good alternative. Check it out. I used lists (and tested on a randomly generated 1Mil numbers and it run in seconds on a average laptop). I believe working with lists will be much faster than df.loc

```
CONSTANT = 1
d, c = [], []
a = [7, 2, 3]
c.append(100)
d.append(c[0] * (a[0] * CONSTANT + 1))
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    d.append(d[i-1] * (a[i] * CONSTANT + 1))
c = c + [x for x in d[:-1]]
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":a, "c":c, "d":d})
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You might try this;

```
col1 = [df.c.values[0]]
col2 = [(df.a.values[0] * df.c.values[0]) + df.c.values[0]]

for i in range(1, len(df.index)):
    col2.append(col2[i-1] + (df.a.values[i] * col2[i-1]))
    col1.append(col2[i-1])

df['c'] = col1
df['d'] = col2

   a       c       d
0  7   100.0   800.0
1  2   800.0  2400.0
2  3  2400.0  9600.0
```